# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'websiteId' of undefined

Tags: error, magento2.4, console

I can see this error on any page. I'm not sure what caused this error
[image]

Do you have any solution?I'm new to Magento,Could you tell me the specific solution

thank you very much!!

Comment: Have you check by disabling the third party extension one by one?

Comment: I could try, but that wouldn't go wrong, would it?

Comment: @Bob, whats on ids-storage-compare.js:77 ? And whats the full path ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using page-empty template.